# How to import properly 3rd party libraries into Laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel, import, scotch-panels

My problem is, I don't know how to install properly scotch-panels in Laravel project. I installed scotch-panels by:

`npm install scotch-panels`

and compile it by:

`npm run dev`

but I have error in console, when I used function from scotch-panels library:

`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).scotchPanel is not a function`

I tried extract module to `vendor.js` (like [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mix) said), but node states:

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'scotch-panels' in [...]`

Unfortunately, link manually library it's not a option. I add that jQuery of course works properly.

I tried with other modules but once it's working, once not. I really don't know, what happened here.

Any help is highly appreciated with this, because I'm confused now.

Comment: Try doing this instead `npm install scotch-panels --save` then `require()` it in your `resources/js/app.js` file (ofc this is supposing that your app.js file is by laravel's mix)

Comment: @yak0d3 I'm not sure that I used reqiure good way but it's not working. I tried 'require('scotch-panels');' and 'require('./node-modules/scotch-panels');' And yes, my app.js file is by laravel's mix.